# Find distinct IDs based on criteria of multiple columns [ANSI SQL]

Tags: sql

I have a table which shows usage history of different tools of each user by date. What I want to do is find users who use any one of 3 particular tools but not any of two other particular types of tools.

[image: Sample data]

In the above example (attached as image), say I want users who use either of a, b or c but don't use d or e simultaneously. So the values I want returned are ID - 3, 4 as they're using one or more of a, b, c but none of either d or e. In my example I've mentioned only one date but the data in the table is of a long duration. I'd like to see overall results from all time data that we have. I've not been able to come up with a code for this although the use case is very straightforward. Would appreciate some help here.

PS - I'm doing this on an analytics tool (zoho) and not a particular type of database. The tool supports querying in multiple SQL dialects.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) so that the test data can be copied to test out possible answers. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking for a better method to show the table.

Comment: @jarlh That's the sample data. The expect result is just the distinct IDs. I'll update the post soon to show both as tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below

```
select distinct A.id from
(    
select id from tablename where toolname in ('a','b','c')
)A left join
(
select id from tablename where toolname in ('d','e')
)B on A.id =B.id where B.id is null
```

Comment: I tried this out. It shows the error - "Unknown table or alias 't' used in select query." I don't think it's possible to reference the table t in select statement of t1 (I'm not sure as I'm new to SQL). When I remove the 'not exists......' part, the code runs. Hence, I think it's something to do with the select of that part. Any idea?

Comment: @Rakshit, I've updated the query using left join - you can give a try

Comment: Thanks for this. I've modified the code (made the edit) a bit and that worked perfectly :) (edit at the beginning- select distinct A.id from...)

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions in the `HAVING` clause to make sure there are a, b or c toolnames, but no d or e.

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having sum(case when toolname in ('a','b','c') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when toolname in ('d','e') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't want to exclude all when tool name is not a, b, c. There are toolnames from a to z say, I just want to see which users are using a or b or c but not d or e specifically (they can be using other tools say x, y, z and that doesn't matter). Does the code you've posted do that exactly? (I'm new to sql so might not have understood your code accurately)

Comment: Now edited. Note that the table will only be read once this way.